# Notation of UML class diagram

Tags: c++, oop, uml, class-diagram

I have the following class cDrawObjectCreator:

```
class cDrawObjectCreator
{
public:
    cDrawObjectCreator( cCompositeRoot *compositeObject ) { m_compositeRoot = compositeObject; }
   ~cDrawObjectCreator() {};
   ...
private:
    cCompositeRoot *m_compositeRoot;
};
```

It is correct diagram?

[image]

or the following diagram is correct?

[image]

Comment: I'd worry less about the diagrams and more about your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one again. For the same reasons as in the previous Question.

Please read [this](http://design-antony.blogspot.com/2007/07/aggregation-vs-composition.html), to see the difference between ***Compostion*** and ***Aggregation***.

Comment: Hm... When I must use not filled  diamond http://habreffect.ru/files/cb6/ecb3b6a09/5.png ?

Comment: Just look up the difference between composition and aggregation. Here for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram

Comment: Why in the composite pattern relation between component and composite is not filled, but this is container and all elements will be deleted when will be delete composite http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Diagrams/composite.gif

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, aggregation (hollow diamond) is a specialization of association, and composition (filled diamond) is a specialization of aggregation.

Remember the purpose of modeling is to facilitate communication so you would use different level of abstractions depending on the purpose and the stakeholders.

If you want to say that cMimicObjectCreator has an exclusive ownership of cCompositeRoot (that is, like a human / an animal body has a brain) then you would use composition (filled diamond). And if you want to say that cMimicObjectCreator has a cCompositeRoot (but not exclusively and that there are cases where the part class is not exist in the whole/container, like say...a boat with a GPS equipment) then you would use aggregation relationship.

To answer your original question, I think the first diagram is more appropriate. However remember also you can always use association relationship in place of composition or aggregation relationship if you want to be more "general".